# How to fix 'selection rows with criteria in SQL'

Tags: sql, r

I'd like select some rows on my outcome depending a variable. 
I want all for all custumers, all rows where variable 'FLG_NEW_RM'=0 and just the first row where 'FLG_NEW_RM'=1. 
Example : I try to fix that with row_number function in sql. But I didn't get nothing

My code :

```
SELECT A.*
,ROW_FROM TABLE ANUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CLT,FLG_NEW_RM ORDER BY MONTH_NEXT,FLG_NEW_RM DESC ) AS ID
FROM TABLE A
```

Actual results :

```
CLT MONTH_NEXT  FLG_NEW_RM  ID
C1  01/11/2016  0           1
C1  01/12/2016  0           2
C1  01/01/2017  0           3
C1  01/02/2017  0           4
C1  01/03/2017  1           1
C1  01/04/2017  1           2
C1  01/05/2017  1           3
C2  01/11/2016  0           1
C2  01/12/2016  0           2
C2  01/07/2017  1           1
C2  01/08/2017  1           2
C2  01/09/2017  1           3
```

Expected results

```
CLT MONTH_NEXT  FLG_NEW_RM
C1  01/11/2016  0
C1  01/12/2016  0
C1  01/01/2017  0
C1  01/02/2017  0
C1  01/03/2017  1
C2  01/11/2016  0
C2  01/12/2016  0
C2  01/07/2017  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `lag()`:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             lag(FLG_NEW_RM) over (partition by clt order by month_next) as prev_fnr
      from a
     ) a
where FLG_NEW_RM = 0 or prev_fnr = 0 or prev_fnr is null;
```

I added the last condition so you'll get the row when the first row for a group is "1".  I think that is implied by your logic.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM 
  TABLE A 
 WHERE FLG_NEW_RM=0 OR (FLG_NEW_RM=1 AND ID=1);